# Names of the proposals for higher $p$-form non-abelian gauge symmetries

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, yang-mills

Beyond 1-form non-abelian YM theories with

$$F=dA+A^2$$

What are the alternative names and proposals to generalize YM to non-abelian higher $p$-forms? What is the current state-of-art of those?

Remark: Does a generalized YM with formal expression

$$F=dA+A^2+A^3$$ and

$$F=dA+A^2+A^3+A^4$$ and more generally speaking

$$F=dA+A^2+A^3+\cdots +A^{p+2}$$

where the latter is written for a $$F_{p+2}$$ p-form has any sense? It seems to me that if A were a 1-form d-should be higher order derivative and/or the A of the latter be different to the A in the non-abelian part such as

$$F_{p+2}=dA_{p+1}+\sum_{i}A_i^qB_i^s$$

with $d$ a derivative of order one operator (exterior derivative usual), and $(A,B)$ certain q-s forms...At least, it seems that the higher order non-abelian YM theory offers opportunities and issues related to the need to add and extra field...I see no natural or easy way to create generalized non abelian YM fields (I am aware of non-abelian CS forms in odd-dimensions but I believe CS are NOT YM theories so they do not apply to this generalization, I presume).

Comment: Have you looked at [Baez & Huerta](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.4485) and other references in [nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/higher+gauge+field#references)?

Comment: quick comment, writing $dA + A \wedge A + A \wedge A \wedge A + ...$ for some 1-form A say, doesn't really make sense for degree reasons.
You higher terms don't live in the same degrees.
Now you can write it as $...\oplus ...$ and consider $\Omega^\bullet$ as a whole.

Comment: @thecakeisLie Obviously, there is a grade form issue there, but A and A could be different p-forms...Maybe I should rewrite it, but the below text I think clarified the issue of the graded p-forms...

Comment: @riemannium (btw great name), yes I see now. Like you point out you can indeed write down $\Omega^n \cong \sum_{n = i+j}\Omega^i \otimes \Omega^j $ when such forms are valued in $\mathbb{C}$, but I'm not sure what is possible when forms are valued in some lie algebra.
Actually now that I think on it, this is why higher gauge theories are restricted to some groups.
I would read the paper mentioned above, it's a great introduction, the U(1) bundle comes to mind.
not an expert btw, I've read that paper a while ago and haven't worked on it much.